# How can I simulate a rigid bounced from a wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations, rigid-body-dynamics

How can I simulate a rigid sword bounced from a wall and hit the ground(like in physical world)?

I want to simulate a simple animation.

The sword is controlled by a center/mass point.(Actually finally it't in a game engine).

I can detect the figure and the size of the sword(maybe needed in doing bounce).

And the position is $\{x,y,z\}$

rotation can be controled by quaternions/matrix/euler angles.[In mathematica, by default is matrix]

## Step1

---

```
point1 = {0, 0, 500};point2 = {500, 0, 500};
```

Fly 500 miles. (Here I can add an acceleration)

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Cuboid[{600, -100, 400}, {510.1, 200, 600}],   GeometricTransformation[swordX[[1]],    TranslationTransform /@ {point1, point2}]}, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

As you see in the picture, my sword inserted into the `Red` wall.

## step2

---

sword bounced from the wall, It should turn the head and do rotations and fly to the ground.

Something like a projectile

How can I simulate this physical process?

Maybe what I need is an equation and some parameters?

Any references?

I've played with this  *Mathematica*  Demonstration [model](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RotationAndTranslationOfARigidBody/), and I've made a video before.

And I need make it more physical, especially how the sword hit and bounced from the wall and fly like a hammer in this model...

[video[03:07]](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNDcyNTkzMjQw.html)

## step3

---

hit the ground, (maybe can bounce from the ground and hit again...)

Some model maybe the same as that in step2.

---

I have no physical engines in Mathematica, if you know, welcome to tell me something related.

Comment: Have you considered [momentum conservation](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/u4l2b.cfm)?

Comment: @KyleKanos ?what do you mean? When sword hit on the ground for several times, it'll stop, of course.

Comment: Obviously, but it is a starting point, isn't it?